# ASP.NET:Update sql table row programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a data conduit class where I want to create an update method that takes list of parameter names, their values and a stored procedure name. Up on execution, I want to update a particular row in sql db.

The code so far in data conduit class is:

```
public class clsDataConduit
{
    SqlConnection Conn= new SqlConnection();
    SqlDataReader rdr= null;
    SqlDataAdapter dataChannel = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder();
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    List<SqlParameter> SQLParams = new List<SqlParameter>();
    DataTable queryResults = new DataTable();
    DataRow newRecord;


        public void NewRecord(string SProcName)
        {
           //works fine
        }


        public void UpdateRecord(string SProcName)
        {

        Conn= new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        //open the database
        Conn.Open();
        //initialise the command builder for this connection
        SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand(SProcName, Conn);
        //add the parameters to the command builder
        //loop through each parameter
        for (int Counter = 0; Counter < SQLParams.Count; Counter += 1)
        {
            //add it to the command builder
            dataCommand.Parameters.Add(SQLParams[Counter]);
        }
        dataCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        dataChannel = new SqlDataAdapter(SProcName, Conn);

        dataChannel.UpdateCommand = dataCommand;
        commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataChannel);

        dataChannel.Update(queryResults);

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Method runs fine till above code, BUT I am not too sure 
        // how to write the rest of the code so that It updates a 
        // a particular row in sql
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //get the structure of a single record
        //newRecord = queryResults.NewRow();   //from previous method - new data


        Conn.Close();
        }
}
```

I am not too sure how can I continue further from this point. If someone can help me out please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, you have already filled the command with the appropriate parameters (with values already set), so you need only to call

```
dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is all you need, (of course the SQLParams list should be already filled with the parameters and their values). Also, to be more generic, you could pass to the UpdateRecord, the list of SqlParameter to use for the storedprocedure called

```
public void UpdateRecord(string SProcName, List<SqlParameters> prms)
{
    using(Conn= new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        //open the database
        Conn.Open();
        //initialise the command builder for this connection
        SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand(SProcName, Conn);
        //add the parameters to the SqlCommand
        dataCommand.Parameters.AddRange(prms.ToArray());
        dataCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, oohhh yea, thanks, silly mistakes you do while coding for the whole day, thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to be of help. If the answer helps you remember to accept it.